# Fastest approximative methods to convert YUV to RGBA?

Tags: c, algorithm, video, image-processing

I am looking for a fastest method to convert one [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) array into [RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA) array. For example, given a YCbYCr array, which is a sequence of bytes:

```
YCbYCr = Luma0, Cb0, Luma1, Cr0, Luma2, ...
```

where 8-bit blue- and 8-bit red- difference chroma components are sampled with period 2, but 8-bit luma is sampled with period 1. For example:

1. image pixel (0,0) has luma0, Cr0 red-difference chroma, Cb0 blue-difference chroma
2. image pixel (0,1) has luma1, Cr0 red-difference chroma, Cb0 blue-difference chroma
3. image pixel (0,2) has luma2, Cr1 red-difference chroma, Cb1 blue-difference chroma
4. image pixel (0,3) has luma3, Cr1 red-difference chroma, Cb1 blue-difference chroma
5. etc.

RGBA array should be produced which is:

```
RGBA = R0, G0, B0, A0, R1, G1, ...
```

where all elements are unsigned chars and all bits of each A# are zero.

Luma component in YCbYCr is 0..255 unsigned char, Cb and Cr are -127..+126 signed chars. There is a standard approach --- matrix multiplication, but it's very slow for real time apps and it operates with floating point numbers. I am looking for a fast approximate numerical method.

Comment: How accurate do you need?  Note that you could do all the calculations in fixed-point instead, with no tangible drop in accuracy.

Comment: @Oli: It could be inaccurate.

Comment: @psihodelia: Inaccurate can mean many things.  I can do R=G=B=0.5, which is as fast as you're possibly going to get, but pretty inaccurate.  The answer would also depend on factors such as what platform you're on.  You could, for instance, approximate the matrix coefficients with shifts and adds, but that may be slower than multiplies on many platforms.

Comment: @Oli: I need some info about pixels' colors, but not too much. Maybe 3-4 bits for each color component of RGB could be enough. Matrix muls or shifts-adds are slow. I am looking for a smart approximative method, I believe should exist.

Comment: @psihodelia: I don't believe you'll find one.  You've got 9 multiplies to produce 3 independent outputs.  There's simply not enough calculation there that can be "approximated", other than by reducing the precision of the coefficients (i.e. via shift-and-add).

Comment: @psihodelia: Ah, I didn't notice that you have subsampled chroma.  Well, of course, you could save some of the multiplies by only calculating the partial sums of the chroma contributions half as often.

Comment: This is one of those (rare) places that attempting to optimize the algorithm probably isn't going to get you very far, but "micro" optimization of the implementation probably will. In particular, you *really* want to implement this to run on the GPU instead of the CPU. This is *exactly* the sort of problem for which the GPU was designed; even the most trivial implementation will beat a CPU by a wide margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest single computational saving you're likely to get is simply by doing the computation in fixed-point rather than floating-point.  It's likely to be an order of magnitude faster (at a guess).

You can also take advantage of the redundancy in the subsampled chroma contributions.  Given that the full matrix multiply is of the form:

```
R     a b c   Y
G  =  d e f . Cb
B     g h i   Cr
```

You can compute the chroma partial sum half as often:

```
R'    b c   
G' =  e f . Cb
B'    h i   Cr
```

and then simply add it to the luma contribution at the full output rate:

```
R     R'     a
G  =  G'  +  d . Y
B     B'     g
```